# AdMob no reaction on click

Tags: android, admob

I'm currently developing an app with AdMob. I have followed all instruction from official admob (BannerExample) and though I managed to display the ads, but there's no reaction when I click on it. Does anyone has a clue why is so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If not ^, your layout file might have some answers.

Comment: Yes, check your logs to see if any errors are being reported, and check your layout files to make sure you haven't overlaid some other view on top of the AdView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Finally find my answer. I found that my layout is overlapping each other. That's why the ads seems no reaction. Once I've fixed the layout, the ad works perfectly.